# Checking N times if matrix[N][N] is = to a symbol

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a very basic Tic-Tac-Toe  with a matrix[N][N].
How can I check for every row, column and diagonal if every matrix index is for example 'X' or 'O'?
For example, if I have a matrix[10][10], how can I check if the first row contains all 'X'?
The language is C, and I have to do it without any complex thing, I can use only while loop, for, etc, not functions or anything else. TY!

EDIT: This is the code I tried to write (it checks if every diagonal symbol is 'X' or 'O'), and it actually works, but only for a 3x3 matrix (classic tic-tac-toe). The thing i want is to make it work for a NxN matrix.

```
  for (i=0; i<MAX; i++){
            if (matrix[i-1][i-1] == 'X' && matrix[i][i] == 'X' && matrix[i+1][i+1] == 'X')
                flagC=1;
            else if (matrix[i-1][i-1] == 'O' && matrix[i][i] == 'O' && matrix[i+1][i+1] == 'O') 
                flagC=1;
```

Comment: [`memcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp), maybe?

Comment: @SouravGhosh As I said, I can use only while loops , for etc, I can't use any function or whatever it is ( I don't even know what's that memcmp() ). I'm programming at a very low level because I'm a student and I got to do it as teachers ask me to. ^^'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort to solve the programming problem.

Comment: Did you check the hyperlink? FWIW, `main()` is also a function, nonetheless. How do you plan to avoid it, then?

Comment: Maybe show us what you tried?

Comment: @RSahu , Only because I didn't put any code doesn't mean I haven't try to solve that problem, I've been trying to solve it for 3 days, but as I said I'm a student and so a newbie.

Comment: @kHz-, you probably have but you haven't "shown" us your effort.

Comment: @RSahu & Kotshi, i've put the code of the check

Comment: @kHz-, you need to have the following checks: matching row 1, matching row 2, matching row 3, matching column 1, matching column 2, matching column 3, matching positive diagonal, matching negative diagonal. The are 8 check totals. You can put the first six in a for loop but the diagonal checks will be easier with simplified, hard coded index based checks.

Comment: @RSahu that's the problem. I can check if a column or a row contains all 'X' or 'O' but only if it's a 3x3, the problem if that I have to extend the algorithm for a NxN matrix, so a general one.

Answer (score 0):

```
char check_row(char** matrix, int row, char value)
{
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if(matrix[row][i] != value)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

char check_col(char** matrix, int col, char value)
{
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if(matrix[i][col] != value)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

If to speak about diagonal, you should first decide how to denote it's number. It's not difficult, just think a bit. In diagonal row number is equal to column number (or N - column number).

Comment: sorry but that's already too complex for the level i'm programming at. I think the 2 things you wrote (char check_row etc.etc.) are functions or whatever? We still did not do this things, so I couldn't actually use that

Comment: @kHz- You could take the code out of the functions and put it in your main if your school doesn't allow you to use functions for now. I don't recommend this practice though, functions are a basic programming tools, in my school, we get taught how to use them the very first day.

Answer (score 0):

So with a little bit of thought, rows and columns are fairly easy to check:

```
// Check rows for 'X'
int check;
for(row=0; row<N; row++)
{
    check = 1;

    for(col=0; col<N; col++)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col] != 'X')
            check = 0;
    }
    if(check)
        printf("A row is full of 'X'\n");
}

//Check cols for 'X'
for(col=0; col<N; col++)
{
    check = 1;
    for(row=0; row<N; i++)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col] != 'X')
            check = 0;
    }
    if(check)
        printf("A col is full of 'X'\n");
}
```

Diagonals are a little trickier but not much. This will check top left to bottom right:

```
// Check diagonals for 'X'
int check = 1;
for(col=0; col<N; col++)
    if(matrix[col][col] != 'X')
        check = 0;
```

To check top right to bottom left we can start at the top right and decrease the col value instead:

```
// Check opposite diagonals for 'X'
int check = 1;
for(col=N-1; col >= 0; col--)
    if(matrix[col][col] != 'X')
        check = 0;
```

Note I haven't tested this and it is just pseudo code. You can hopefully adapt this to your code though :)

Comment: I've already tried this before, and it won't work. That's because if matrix[row][col] is != 'X', it will put the check to 0. For example: col and row is = 0 at first for cycle, if matrix[0][0] is != 'X', it will put the check to 0, without checking the other elements of row or column.

Comment: Yes which is what you want it to do when you're checking for a full row or column of 'X' :).

You have to search 'X' and 'O' separately using this method. Or you could define two 'checks' checkX and checkO for example to save you writing two loops.

What I wrote is about half the code you'd need. I'm pretty sure this works though.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I take your point. I have updated my code with some minor corrections to fix this. I have also tested it this time and guarantee it works :).

Comment: actually it only put the check = 0 also if only one element of the row\column is 'X', i need to put the check = 0 when EVERY element of row\column is 'X', since the code is written in a while loop, and while loop will stop when check != 0!

Comment: also tried changing it as the edited code, but it's actually the same. My program still end at the first move, because the flag (check) will be ALWAYS 0 after the first move with the control you've put, since it only needs one 'X' in a row\column to get check=0 ^^'

Comment: I just defined a random flag called check. I wasn't suggesting this would form the criteria of a while loop condition. This code just does what you asked which is checks an NxN grid for any complete rows, columns or diagonals of 'X' or 'O'. How you implement this is up to you :) You need to run this check every step. Check should indeed be zero at the end of the first move because there are no complete rows or columns yet. That's all this code checks. You then ask the players for another move, fill the grid in appropriately and repeat the check process :).

Comment: I'd really like to show you the code I have wrote but seems like I can't though ^^' seems like I won't solve that problem unfortunately, but I'm not blaming you obviously, it's me. :D